# Why do I get Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to load data from a SQL database using MVC5 and AngularJS. The back-end code works fine and I can get the data but it's not being populated into my table.

My Index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="StudentCtrl">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable datatable">
            <thead class="grid-top-panel">
                <tr>
                    <th>StudentID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="dataModel in students">
                    <td>{{dataModel.StudentID}}</td>
                    <td>{{dataModel.FirstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{dataModel.LastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{dataModel.Email}}</td>
                </tr>  
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptsNg/Module/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptsNg/Controller/StudentController.js"></script>
<script src="~/ScriptsNg/Services/StudentService.js"></script>
```

app.js:

```
var app;
(function () {
    'use strict';   
    app = angular.module('myapp', ["ngRoute"]);
})();
```

StudentService.js:

```
app.service('StudentService', function ($http) {
    //**********----Get All Record----***************  
    var urlGet = '';
    this.getAll = function (apiRoute) {
        urlGet = apiRoute;
        return $http.get(urlGet);
    }
});
```

StudentController.js:

```
app.controller('StudentCtrl', ['$scope', 'StudentService',
    // we inject StudentService  inject because we call getAll method for get all student  
    function ($scope, StudentService) {
        // this is base url   
        var baseUrl = '/api/student/';
        // get all student from databse  
        $scope.getStudents = function () {
            var apiRoute = baseUrl + 'GetStudents/';
            var _student = StudentService.getAll(apiRoute);
            _student.then(function (response) {
                $scope.students = response.data;
            },
                function (error) {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });

        }
        $scope.getStudents();

    }]);
```

Some posts suggested I add the angular-route script on my index page and inject the ngRouter library into my module. I did and I'm still getting the same error:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/modulerr?

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please use the non-minified angular.js during development, the error messages will be more clear

Comment: Thanks @devqon I changed my script to use the non-minified script and now get this error: 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myapp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myapp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: In the console can you confirm your scripts are all coming across properly?

Comment: Thanks @Mickers I was referencing my scripts from the wrong folder so it wasn't getting the module, controller and service scripts. The data is pulling through now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Module, controller and services scripts were being loaded from the wrong folder so they weren't coming through. I changed them to be referenced from the correct scripts folder